# Integrate paypal payment method on magento

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

I'm trying to integrate paypal payment method on a Magento site.  Where can I get the following info.

[Paypal Api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/femZR.jpg)

[Third party permission api username](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1BRq.jpg)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: magento version

Comment: Magento ver. 1.9.3.6

Answer (score 0):

First go to paypal and create a developer account using link

https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/

and go to this link to integrate sandbox

https://www.paypal.com/in/selfhelp/article/how-do-i-integrate-paypal-payments-standard-with-magento-2.0-ts2104

Comment: After creating a developer account. Whats next? where can i get the api username. passwordand signature?

Comment: You have Trader or business account

Comment: where will i get this Third Party Permission Username?

Comment: It works in sandbox mode but it did not work when I turn it off.

Comment: So for this raise, a ticket in the panel for support might there is some charge or need some auditing to whitelist your web Application for Paypal

Comment: Thanks, @Santosh. I appreciate your help.